# What is the purpose and function of Xcode's source control "Show Remote Status" menu option?

Tags: xcode, git, menu, xcode4.5, git-remote

When working in Xcode on a project that's under git source control, I noticed the following menu item:

```
File > Source Control > Show Remote Status
```

and, when toggling it, it changes to:

```
File > Source Control > Hide Remote Status
```

I do have a Bitbucket git remote configured for the sample project I'm working on, but I can't figure out what that menu is supposed to be showing me, or where!?  When I toggle it, there is **no visible change** to my Xcode user interface.  I **do** have some changes that were committed to the local git repository *only*, not yet pushed to the remote, and I was expecting, somewhere, to see that the remote isn't current, when "Show Remote Status" is toggled on.

So, what *is* this "Remote Status" information that Xcode is supposed to be able to show, and *where* am I supposed to be looking for it?  Is this feature equivalent to something that is typically queried on the git command line – and if so, what?  Is there a window or panel I'm supposed to have open in order to see this information?  I do have my navigator area, debug area, and utility areas all visible.

I searched Xcode documentation, Stack Overflow, and Google each for "Show Remote Status" and "Hide Remote Status", but none of the results were particularly enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Xcode before (yet), but since Git is a distributed version control system, your local repo can become out of sync with the remote repo, i.e. their states can diverge. That is probably why you're given the option to see what the status of the remote is, for example, if any of its branches have been updated (i.e. have new commits), if there are any new branches on it, and if any branches have been deleted from it.

From the command line, you would normally get this kind of information by running `git fetch --prune <remote>` to update your local remote-tracking branches, which track the status of the branches of your remote (of course!). You can then examine the remote-tracking branches to see what the status of the remote repo is.

There is also the `git ls-remote <remote>` command, which will do a network operation to talk to the remote and return a list of the remote's current references/branches, but that is more of a plumbing command that is not really meant for typical Git users, it's more meant for Git developers to create Git tools.